# JS Формы, отображение введенного

Tags: javascript

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы fff() выполнялась снизу формы?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fff()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    document.write(x);
    return false;   
}
</script>

<form name="myForm" href="" onsubmit="return fff();" >
        id: <input type="number" value="Текст" name="fname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я совершенно уверен, что у Вас в  мозгу понятие "выполнялась снизу формы" - что-то очень простое и ясное. Но только у Вас.

Comment: Из самого очевидного - расположить скрипт ниже формы?)

Comment: @Igor, предполагается, что существует некоторая область (пустая строка, например), которая  на странице находится ниже формы.

Comment: @ThisMan Это не работает.

Comment: Хм, ну поместите в эту строку: `<script>fff();</script>`

Comment: забыл поставить тег *sarcasm*, добавьте ваше пояснение в вопрос, а не в комментарий. Так любой сможет увидеть это пояснение, а не рыться в комментариях

Comment: кстати говоря, вызов `document.write` после загрузки страницы, перепишет всю страницу

Comment: @Igor, но функция должна выполняться после нажатия "Отправить"

Comment: @Olfy - та-ак, возвращаемся к моему первому комментарию. Сейчас что не работает?

Comment: @Igor с помощью какой функции можно не переписывать всю страницу?

Comment: @Igor Сейчас перезагружается страница, и на ней отображается только выполнение fff()

Comment: `<div id="output"></div>` и `document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вызов `document.write` после загрузки страницы, перепишет всю страницу

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fff()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    //document.write(x);
    document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;
    return false;   
}
</script>

<form name="myForm" href="" onsubmit="return fff();" >
  id: <input type="number" value="Текст" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```